# Why does this code print 0

Tags: c++, variables, pointers, memory

Why does the following code print 0? i.e. why does variable `a` is located right after variable `d`, even though pointer variable `c` is being declared between them?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    unsigned int a = 100;
    unsigned int &b = a;
    unsigned int *c = &b;
    unsigned int d = (unsigned int)(c);
    int e = &d - c;
    int &f = e;
    e ++;
    cout << e << " " << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Subtracting pointers to unrelated objects is undefined behaviour. The compiler can produce whatever code it likes. And it did.

Comment: And that doesn't print a 0, for me it prints a 2?

Comment: I can't even get this to compile: `test.cc:8:22: error: cast from pointer to smaller type 'unsigned int' loses information`

Comment: prints 2: http://ideone.com/auIjUO

Comment: Aside for the fact that the code performs illegal operations that lead to undefined behavior, the language makes no guarantees on how local variables are allocated. So, there's no reason to expect anything specific here. Any result is as good as the next one. There's no "why" here.

Comment: The compiler probably optimized variable `c` out completely.

Comment: @Cubbi: What compiler did you use?  It's broken, a compiler is allowed to generate a warning for narrowing conversions but not an error.  Try removing `-Werror` from your options.

Comment: @BenVoigt I didn't use `-Werror`. I used `clang++-3.3` and `g++-4.8.1` with no options at all. (FWIW, icc-13.1.3 only issued a warning). The standard addresses this conversion under 5.2.10/4, which says 'A pointer can be explicitly converted to any integral type large enough to hold it'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working backwards:

```
e ++;
cout << e << " " << endl;
```

If this prints 0, then the value of `e` before executing this code must have been `-1`.

```
int e = &d - c;
```

So the result of the above address subtraction must have been `-1`.

```
unsigned int a /* = whatever, the value of a doesn't matter */;
unsigned int &b = a;
unsigned int *c = &b;
unsigned int d /* = whatever, the value of d doesn't matter */;
```

`b` is a reference to `a`, so `&b` is equivalent to `&a`.

So `&d - c` is equivalent to `&d - &a`, and that subtraction yields `-1`.

Conclusion: the address of `d` is `sizeof (unsigned int)` bytes *after* the address of `a`. (Pointer subtraction is scaled by the size of the pointed-to type.)

Probably.

In fact, the behavior of subtracting pointers to two independently defined objects is *undefined*. The standard says literally nothing about what it should do.

In practice, a compiler will probably generate the simplest possible code for a pointer subtraction, and that simple code will probably treat unrelated pointers *as if* they were comparable, even though the language doesn't say they are.

It's likely, given your program's output, that `b` and `d` happen to be allocated next to each other. Nothing says that declared variables have to be allocated in the order in which you declare them. If you want objects to be allocated in memory in a define order, put them into a `struct` or make them elements of an array.

It's also likely that the same program will yield different results if you run it on a different system, or on the same system with a different compiler, or on the same system with the same compiler with different compiler options. In principle, it could even behave differently with everything the same but during a different phase of the moon.

And a compiler is permitted to *assume* that your code's behavior is well defined, and perform transformations that are valid only given that assumption. In effect, by subtracting two unrelated pointers, you have promised the compiler that they both point to elements of the same array object or just past the end of it (where a single object is treated as a 1-element array) (or that both are null pointers; that's one difference between C and C++). You have lied to the compiler, which means it is under no further obligation to you.

Don't do that.

Comment: `b` is actually a reference bound to `a`, so the "working backwards" process should technically include one extra step: `&b` is actually `&a`, which means that `&d - c` is equivalent to `&d - &a`. But the OP apparently knows that already, since this is exactly what is stated in the question.

Comment: @AndreyT: Ah, I missed the reference. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you explicitly place objects using your own memory management system, their relative positions in memory will be compiler- and system-dependent.

Answer (score -1):

your line `int e = &d - c;` is substracting 2 `unsigned int *`.

In memory, `&d` is 8 bytes farther then `c` (it depend on your system, but we suppose that an `int` is 4 bytes). Effectively, you construct your stack in this way :

```
unsigned int a = 100;                // &a is 0x0
unsigned int &b = a;                 // &b is 0x0 (it's just an alias)
unsigned int *c = &b;                // &c is 0x4
unsigned int d = (unsigned int)(c);  // &d is 0x8
```

An `unsigned int` use 4 bytes in memory.
So, when your are doing `&d - c`, it must return `2`, because your are using pointer arithmetics with `unsigned int*` (4*2=8);

You can try with `int e = (short*)&d - (short*)c` result should be `4` because `short` size is 2 (2*4=8).

You can try with `int e = (char*)&d - (char*)c` result should be `8` because `char` size is 1 (1*8=8).

Try to print your variables and addresses to understand :

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main () {
  unsigned int a = 100;
  unsigned int &b = a;
  unsigned int *c = &b;
  unsigned int d = (unsigned int)(c);
  int e = (short*)&d - (short*)c;
  //int &f = e;                                                                                                                                                                  
  //e ++;                                                                                                                                                                        

  cout << "&a: " << (unsigned int)&a << endl;
  cout << "&b: " << (unsigned int)&b << endl;
  cout << "&c: " << (unsigned int)&c << endl;
  cout << "&d: " << (unsigned int)&d << endl;

  cout << endl;

  cout << " a: " << a << endl;
  cout << " b: " << b << endl;
  cout << " c: " << (unsigned int)c << endl;
  cout << " d: " << d << endl;

  cout << endl;

  cout << " e: " << e << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Here, with `int e = (short*)&d - (short*)c;`, result is :

```
&a: 3220197356
&b: 3220197356
&c: 3220197360
&d: 3220197364

 a: 100
 b: 100
 c: 3220197356
 d: 3220197356

 e: 4
```